# collect user inputs using Nodejs and Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm new with Node.js I want to collect user data like name, phone number, Gmail, city ...etc using nodejs & stripe. So that I can know the user from stripe dashboard with all their information.

#### server side

```
app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
    try {
        stripe.customers
            .create({
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                source: req.body.stripeToken
            })
            .then(() => res.render("succ.html"))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

when I use this code I just take the name and Gmail from user...IDK what elements can I use to take phone number and city ...etc.

**scripts.js**

```
const stripeTokenHandler = token => {
    const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save the phone number and address in customer object's `shipping` property. See https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-shipping

You might also want to check out [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout). The Checkout page provides built-in input elements to collect customer info, including phone number and billing/shipping address. See https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/phone-numbers